# mysql randomizing result and optimization

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, random

I want to have randomized rows after a query, but using `order by rand()` is just exhausting on a table that has 120k+ rows. I have found a small solution that just outputs number of rows but it runs like it starts from a random index and then returns #number of rows after that. It is pretty fast but this just returns some rows after a random index. The code goes like:

```
SELECT *
FROM lieky AS r1 JOIN 
   (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(col_0)
                    FROM lieky)) AS id)
    AS r2
WHERE r1.col_0 >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.col_0 ASC
LIMIT 100
```

and i found it in here: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Is there something that would help me ?

I am trying to get randomized data into pagination, so when the user queries the database, he will always get the rows in a random order.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that

```
(SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(col_0) FROM lieky)) AS id)
```

can return MAX(col_0), so you ll get only 1 row (because of WHERE r1.col_0 >= r2.id)

I think good solution should be somethink like:

- add two columns groupId int, seed int; add index `indexName` (groupId , seed)
- every x seconds (maybe every hour, day, ..) run script that ll be recalc these columns (see below)
- when user open your rows list first time (or when you want to re-rand items) you save any random groupId to user's session; groupId can be from 0 to (select max(groupId) from lieky)
- to show rows you use query like: (select * from lieky where groupId=%saved groupId% order by Seed limit x,100) — it should be very fast

About recalc script, it ll rather slow (so it's good idea to run it at night).
Seed you can update by using:

```
update lieky set Seed = rand()*1000000
```

Then set GroupId=0 for first N rows, GroupId=1 for following N rows, ...
N is max rows that you can show for user (max_page)*(per_page_count)

Comment: Well yeah that is also a possibility but I would rather make it after every click. Thank you